# How can you convert 180 rotation into two separate motions?

Tags: mechanical, linear-motion, servo, prototyping

I have a small servo that can rotate 180 degrees. I would like to get two different connected parts to move at different times, one part moving while the servo is between 0-90 degrees, the other part moving between 90-180 degrees, similar to the diagram. Due to space concerns I can't extend mechanisms above or below the pivots. Another constraint is that it can't rely on gravity, since the mechanisms might be in any orientation when used or idle. It's fine if there's a small range where both parts move. [image: motion diagram]

My current thoughts have been to try and design a pin-slot track system, but I haven't been able to think of a way to  get both parts on the track and I feel like that's overcomplicating it.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the device's context? It would save us going down dead-ends proposing mechanisms that won't fit.

Comment: I would suggest looking into geneva wheel mechanisms, as long as the direction of rotation of your parts relative to the motor are always the same a geneva wheel should work.

Comment: Have a look at car wiper systems.

Comment: @Transistor Here's an image I have on hand of an early design (I've moved from Sketchup to Fusion 360, but the idea is still the same) https://i.imgur.com/opnK71n.png It's a door that covers the content of a platform, and the platform moves upwards to reveal it's content. It's for a costume, and the area under the servo would be the wearer's arm. Ideally the door would open before the platform would start to rise up. I'm OK with changing the platform mechanism, but I want to keep the door hinge so that the gap is minimal when closed. 9G Servo for comparison.